# How can `$?` after while loop not be a value that would have terminated the while loop?

Tags: bash, while-loop, mkdir, exit-code, built-in

I have this code fragment in a bash function:

```
while ! mkdir lock ; do
    inotifywait -t $WAIT_TIMEOUT -e delete_self lock
done
local es=$?
if (( $es != 0 )); then
    echo "Checkpoint A"
    exit $es
fi
```

I thought that checkpoint A would be completely unreachable (since a successful mkdir must surely be the last command executed when the while loop terminates).

However, I'm finding that sometimes checkpoint A is reached. How is this possible, even in principle?

Comment: (aside: Any particular reason you're using directory-existance-based locking rather than `flock`? The latter is not only less code, but -- more importantly -- automatically unlocks when the process holding the lock FD exits, even via power loss or other unclean/unexpected condition).

Comment: (second aside: You might consider quoting your expansions unconditionally, even when you know there aren't spaces present inside values. `-t "$WAIT_TIMEOUT"` will allow a more useful error message if the value is unexpectedly unset than `-t $WAIT_TIMEOUT` will, as the former ensures that an empty string is passed in the slot; even more surprising can be behavior with a non-default IFS, which could cause a value of `101` to expand to two separate words if `IFS=0`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for the advice. I'm a complete newbie to Linux and have an aversion to using tools that I suspect "may have issues". The tone of [this](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/locking.html) put me off, for better or worse.

Comment: Nothing in the `flock()` section for that document is untrue, but frankly, I don't believe that any of those issues make it a tool to avoid except in very narrow cases (particularly, filesystems that fail to fully implement the relevant semantics). And frankly, if you're worried about nonstandard or misbehaving filesystem semantics, you have problems with older versions of NFS even if you *don't* use `flock()`.

Comment: It's likewise completely true that `flock()` and `fcntl(LOCK_*)` locks are in separate namespaces and thus don't exclude each other, but that's only a concern when you have two different pieces of software trying to mutually exclude each other while using different calls -- the only case where it's a problem with a single piece of software using identical calls is when one is acting on a filesystem directly, and the other interacting with that same filesystem over (an older version of) NFS.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy A directory is something I can see and touch.. `echo $$>lock/pid` etc. and if deadlocked I can walk around and troubleshoot. Yes, you are right, and I'm just inventing excuses to not have to change my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From section 2.9.4 of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ regardint the exit status of a while loop:

> The exit status of the while loop shall be the exit status of the last
>   compound-list-2 executed, or zero if none was executed.

(Here, "compound-list-2" are the commands inside the `do...done` portion of the while loop.)  So the value of `$?` will be the result returned the last time inotifywait executed, or zero if it is never called.